# Change Background Color of Code Block for org-mode LaTeX export

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, colors

I'm inserting code fragments in an org-mode document like this:

```
#+CAPTION: My Caption
#+NAME: fig:figure_name
#+BEGIN_SRC a_language
My code ...
#+END_SRC
```

In PDF LaTeX export, the code blocks are not easily distinguished from the main text. Ideally, I would like to have a bounding box and/or a light gray background, similar to how Stack Exchange sets apart snippets of code. I've tried changing the LaTeX background color org-mode option, but it didn't seem to do what I want. Is there any easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: Thanks for asking this, this question reminded me, that I had to figure out how this works. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a solution using latex package `lstlisting` instead of `minted`
(lstlisting is not so powerful as minted but does not need a whole python stack).

You need to put following lisp code into your Emacs init.el (or try it in `*scratch*` buffer like I did.

```
(setq org-latex-listings t)
(add-to-list 'org-latex-packages-alist '("" "listings"))
(add-to-list 'org-latex-packages-alist '("" "color"))
```

These lines load the latex packages `listings` and `color` and advice org mode to export code block using the `listings` latex package.

After that you can write your code block that way:

```
#+CAPTION: Caption, my caption!
#+ATTR_LATEX: :options frame=single,backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray}
#+BEGIN_SRC C :results output :exports both
int i, x = 10;
for(i = 0; i < x; i++)
    printf("%d ",i);
printf(" ~ %d\n", x);
#+END_SRC
```

Notice the extra line of
`#+ATTR_LATEX: :options frame=single,backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray}`,
 which defines a frame around the source code and a background color.

---

Above settings should produce following lines (among others) in the resulting `.tex` file:

```
...
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
...
\lstset{language=C,label= ,caption={Caption, my caption!},captionpos=b,numbers=none,frame=single backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray}}
\begin{lstlisting}
int i, x = 10;
for(i = 0; i < x; i++)
    printf("%d ",i);
printf(" ~ %d\n", x);
\end{lstlisting}
```

---

*Remark:* in older Org-Versions (v8 and older) `#+ATTR_LATEX` uses another syntax. Space () instead of `=` is used. The `#+ATTR_LATEX` needs to be changed slightly. Read more [at the question org ignores attr latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237748/emacs-org-mode-ignores-attr-latex)

---

*Note:* here is another solution, using `minted`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60396939